# Matrix Gallery, with every image having it's own unique URL?

Tags: matrix, url, gallery

As of right now I have nine or so structures created, each including it's own Image Gallery created in a Matrix.

Is it possible to give each image inside that matrix a unique URL?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to create multiple galleries, each gallery when clicked will just pull up into a Fancybox. The problem with this, is there also needs to be social media sharing (Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest, and Google+) for each item in the gallery. After a bit of research the Facebook og:image tag only shares what is in that URL being shared. So I will need to be able to create pages for each item in the gallery. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating a "single image" template, and point to that template with a URL GET variable containing the Asset ID, for example:

`http://yoursite.com/gallery/single?assetId=234`

First, create a template for your "single" image – e.g `/templates/gallery/single.twig` (I like to use the twig extension rather than .html, but its not important).

Add the following Twig code to your template – it will look at the current request query string for the `assetId` variable, and try to pull the relevant Asset:

```
{% set assetId = craft.request.getParam( 'assetId' ) %}
{% if assetId %}
{% set asset = craft.assets.id( assetId ).first() %}
{% endif %}
```

Then, you can easily output the image in whatever way you want, here's an example:

```
{% extends 'layouts/myGalleryTemplate' %}
{% block single %}
    {% if asset is defined %}
        <img src="{{ asset.getUrl() }}" width="{{ asset.getWidth() }}" height="{{ asset.getHeight() }}" alt="" />
    {% else %}
        <p class="error">The specified image could not be found</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```